# How to return value at the same column based on the value of the previous row SQL - LAG

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows, logic, lag

I have a problem in SQL and I'm having trouble solving it: I would like to get the first value that was calculated based on other parameters in the table, and then apply a new formula taking the resulting value from the first line:

`

```
  A         B    X    Y     Z   P
    3305623815 0.04 1 5/1/2023 0 0.96
    3305623815 0.04 1 2/5/2023 0 0.92
    3305623815 0.04 1 3/5/2023 0 0.88
    3305623815 0.04 1 4/5/2023 0 0.84
    3305623815 0.04 1 5/5/2023 0 0.8
    3305623815 0.04 1 6/5/2023 0 0.76
    3305623815 0.04 1 7/5/2023 0 0.72
    3305623815 0.04 1 5/8/2023 2 2.68`
```

My goal is to create this column P, to have the value 0.96 (first line), the calculation is: (X-B+Z),
and the value of the next line is given (value of the previous line P1 - B + Z), and of the third line (P2 - B + Z), and so on. I tried using the LAG function, but it is always returning the value of the first line, which is 0.96. Any idea which query to use to return the values ​​of column P?

My goal is to create this column P, to have the value 0.96 (first line), the calculation is: (X-B+Z),
and the value of the next line is given (value of the previous line P1 - B + Z), and of the third line (P2 - B + Z), and so on. I tried using the LAG function, but it is always returning the value of the first line, which is 0.96. Any idea which query to use to return the values ​​of column P?

I want to create the column P(let`s imagine it is not in the table shared), as it is in the table, returning the values based in the previous formula calculation description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the LAG and running SUM window functions as the following:

```
Select A, B, X, Y, Z,
  (X - SUM(lag_B) Over (Partition By A Order By Y) + Z) AS P
From
(
  Select *,
    LAG(B, 1, B) Over (Partition By A Order By Y) lag_B
  From table_name
) T
```

`LAG(B, 1, B)` will return the current B value when there no lag value for B (default value when lag is null).

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BQZFAFLb).